# How to get only the root name in Json

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

Say I have a Json as below:

```
{
    "Records123": {
        "-count": "1",
        "-count2": "2",
        "-count3": "4",
        "Metadata": {
            "value": 2,
            "sum": 5
        }

    }
}
```

1. How do I get only the root name i.e 'Records123' in this case for Json (using Json.net or any method) , the way we have XDocument.Root.Name.LocalName in XML...
2. How to get the Root attributes i.e 'count' in this case like we have XDocument.Root.Attributes() in XML?

Comment: It's the only key in the list of keys of the top level object. What's difficult about that?

Comment: How can i get it using Json.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JObject like this

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
foreach (var tmp in jsonObject) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(tmp.Key);
}
```

For your sample JSON this should give you `Records123` on the console. You have to add some logic here to get the first item only, which is a bit more tricky to `JProperty` handling.

**Edit**

For getting the other properties use

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
foreach(JObject jsonProperty in jsonObject.Children<JProperty>().First())
{
    foreach (var property in jsonProperty.Properties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much @Sprinter252 . How do I solve   "How to get the Root attributes i.e 'count','count2','count3' in this case like we have XDocument.Root.Attributes() in XML?"

Comment: Thanks @Sprinter252